# Cors error when accessing Django Rest API from front end Using Axios

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, axios, django-cors-headers

Accessing django Rest API using axios  gives following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.localhost:8080/auth/register-shop/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I added django cors headers as mention in this link https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

frontend page

```
 axios({
                                method: 'post',
                                url: 'http://api.localhost:8080/auth/register-shop/',
                                //url: 'http://api.yuniq.ml/auth/register-shop/',

                                headers: {
                                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                                        "content-type": "application/json"
                                },
                                data: {

                                        "name": Name,
                                        "address": Address,
                                        "city": City,
                                        "postalC ode": PostalCode,
                                        "telephone": Telephone,
                                        "openTime": Opentime,
                                        "closeTime": Closetime,
                                        "image_url": Image_url  //still not working 

                                }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                        })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                });


                }
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['corsheaders']


MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' , #add cors middleware
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',
]



CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

error not solved after doing this

Comment: Check ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py. Set it as this ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

Comment: also added ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in settings.py

Comment: Remove `Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` from your axios call in your frontend JavaScript code.

Comment: Can't you add access control to your response from django view?
`response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(string))
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        return response`

Comment: still same error occurs

Comment: Try swapping `corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware` and `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and did the below steps:

- I checked what headers are sending from the Axios.
- make sure this package is installed

> 'pip install django-cors-headers'

- 

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...,
        'corsheaders',
        ...
 ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Now there are two options:

1 - Allow access to all domains by just Adding the following variables in settings.py:

> ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
>
> CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

2 - Do not allow access to all the domains, but the one which you are consuming the API. Add the following variables in settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['http://localhost:5000']

> CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
>
> CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
> 'http://localhost:5000', )

Also you can define allow hearders in setting.py if you want to send a specific header with your request.

> CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [   
    ...
    'Currency',
    ...
 ]
```

checking out this can help you:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-django-cors-error

Answer (score 1):

Your axios request should not include this header:
`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",`

That should only be included in the server's response. Try removing it from your axios request.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced same issue and i have solved it. I am also using `corsheaders` to avoid CORS errors and it works fine till i introduce `Authentication`. The same problem starts again for those api's which permission is set to `IsAuthenticated`. So i add the certain host in my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in settings.py and its worked. There are two options to add hosts.

Option 1. `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]`

Option 2. `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['your host1', 'your host2', 'your host3', ......]`.

**NOTE**: I don't prefer Option 1, because it will raise security issues. So choose Option 2.